# Fixing inflexion point estimate using python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to find the inflexion points on a curve using python. The data for the curve is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rig8frgewde8i5n/fitted.txt?dl=0. Please note that the curve has been fitted to the raw data. Raw data is available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lskykdi1ia1lu7/ww.txt?dl=0

```
import numpy as np
# Read in array from text file
arr = np.loadtxt(path_to_file)

inflexion_point_1 = np.diff(arr).argmin()
inflexion_point_2 = np.diff(arr).argmax()
```

These 2 inflexion points are shows as red lines in the attached plot. However, their locations do not seem to be right. The first inflexion point should be close to the area indicated by the black arrow. How do I fix this?

[image]

Also, here is a plot of the differential:

```
plt.axvline(np.gradient(arr[:365]).argmax())
```

As you can see, the code is behaving as coded i.e. it finds the argmax of np.diff of the array. However, I want to find a position closer to day 110 or so, i.e. about half-way to argmax.

[image]

--EDIT--

Also, here is another plot showing thee raw data and the fitted curve (using a quadratic function).

[image]

Comment: I would fit a function to your data and get the derivative of this function. Applying it directly to your data seems to cause issues due to the steps you have.

Comment: thanks @Cleb, I actually do a fit of the data first. The curve that is shown is the fitted line. Will clarify this in question.

Comment: What underlying model do you use for the fit? That looks like a clear overfit to me. Could you modify your plot in such a way that we see the actual datapoints in the plot on which the fit is based?!

Comment: I am using a quadratic fit. will add another plot showing raw data and fitted data.

Comment: According to the second plot you should just find the first point when derivative exceeds some threshold. Or may be you can apply some window function

Comment: Ok, so it is not actually a fit but just smoothing!? I would still try to fit an actual function to the blue line and take then the derivative of it.

Comment: I would suggest either KDE or splines, either way quadratic won't fit well in your data.

Comment: @Cleb, I am doing a fit of a quadratic function using `scipy.optimize.leastsq`. Is that not the right way? What function would you suggest?

Comment: Could you also make your raw data available, then it is easier to play with it.

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/density.html#kernel-density-estimation

Comment: thanks @Cleb, raw data is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lskykdi1ia1lu7/ww.txt?dl=0

Comment: thanks @Mai, sorry I had a brain freeze

Comment: @BobBaxley For a smooth function, an inflection point can also be characterized as a local maximum or local minimum of the first derivative.  If the data were nice and smooth,  `np.diff(arr).argmax()` and `np.diff(arr).argmin()` would be reasonable approaches to estimate the inflection points.  However, the data in this case is noisy, so a simple finite difference does not work well.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser good point and nice catch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any reason not to use uni-variate spline directly on the gradient?

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

#raw data
data = np.genfromtxt('ww.txt')

plt.plot(np.gradient(data), '+')

spl = UnivariateSpline(np.arange(len(data)), np.gradient(data), k=5)
spl.set_smoothing_factor(1000)
plt.plot(spl(np.arange(len(data))), label='Smooth Fct 1e3')
spl.set_smoothing_factor(10000)
plt.plot(spl(np.arange(len(data))), label='Smooth Fct 1e4')
plt.legend(loc='lower left')

max_idx = np.argmax(spl(np.arange(len(data))))
plt.vlines(max_idx, -5, 9, linewidth=5, alpha=0.3)
```

[image]

Also we can solve for the maximum numerically:

```
In [122]:

import scipy.optimize as so
F = lambda x: -spl(x)
so.fmin(F, 102)
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: -3.339112
         Iterations: 20
         Function evaluations: 40
Out[122]:
array([ 124.91303558])
```